# Multiple YouTube thumbnails in the same resolution using JavaScript

Tags: youtube-api, thumbnails, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, video-thumbnails

How to get the multiple Youtube thumbnails in the same resolution?. In YouTube JS API, I get the default, HQ, medium, low-quality images. But, I need multiple thumbnails of the same size. Multiple high-quality thumbnails are much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are video frames thumbnails with the same resolution (120x90)

WebP:

```
frame1: https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/1.webp
frame2: https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/2.webp
frame3: https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/3.webp
```

JPG:

```
frame1: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/1.jpg
frame2: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/2.jpg
frame3: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/3.jpg
```